# Recycler View crashing in the app (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-authentication

I was building a simple Blog App using Firebase. Now when I login from the Login Page I enter this Main Activity that contains a toolbar and a Recycler View . Now when I enter this Activity the app crashes every single time
showing an error in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter .

The following is the code:

```
package com.example.adi.blogger;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static android.R.attr.checkBoxPreferenceStyle;
import static android.R.attr.description;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.L;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;
import static android.transition.Fade.IN;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mListener;
    RecyclerView cardRecyclerView;
    DatabaseReference mainActivityDatabaseReference;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;

    String LOG_TAG ="BOO";

    Toolbar myToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mainActivityDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BLOG_DATA");
        mainActivityDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"YOU ARE JUST UNDER KEP SYNC METHOD");
        myToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        cardRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.blogRecyclerView);
        cardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"YOU ARE UNDER SETLAYOUT MANAGER IN ONCREATE");





        mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

       //mainActivityDatabaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BLOG_DATA");

        mListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

          FirebaseUser mUser =  firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"YOU ARE DEFINITELY ENTERING AUTH STATE LISTENER");
                if(mUser==null){

                    Intent getBackIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    getBackIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(getBackIntent);
                }
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"YOU ARE COMING OUT OF IT NOW");
            }
        };

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"you are in on create option menu");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_xml,menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.addButtonToolbar:
                Intent newBlogIntent = new Intent(this,AddBlog.class);
                startActivity(newBlogIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.signoutButtonToolbar:
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent signOut_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                signOut_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(signOut_intent);
                break;
        }


        return true;


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
Log.e(LOG_TAG,"You are now in onstart method");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Making onstart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mListener);
        checkUserExist();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"You are before creating firebase adapter");
         FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogGS,recyclerBlogView> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BlogGS, recyclerBlogView>(
                BlogGS.class,
                R.layout.blog_row,
                recyclerBlogView.class,
                mainActivityDatabaseReference) {




            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(recyclerBlogView viewHolder, BlogGS model, int position) {
             Log.e(LOG_TAG,"IN POPULATE VIEW");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are entering populate View Holder method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());


              viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());

                viewHolder.setImageurl(getApplicationContext(),model.getImageurl());


            }

        };


        cardRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public  class recyclerBlogView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



        View mView;

        recyclerBlogView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"you are in recyclerBlogView Class");
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title){
            TextView recylerTitle = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);

            recylerTitle.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDescription(String description){
            TextView recyclerConten = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.cardDescription);

            recyclerConten.setText(description);
        }

        public void setImageurl(final Context ctx, final String imageurl){

            final ImageView blogImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blogImageCard);


            Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageurl).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(blogImage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                    Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageurl).centerCrop().into(blogImage);

                }
            });

        }



    }

    private void checkUserExist() {
        System.out.print("CHECK USER ENTERED");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you are entering check user exist method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"check user exist method");
        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                    Intent accountSetupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AccountSetup.class);
                    accountSetupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(accountSetupIntent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**The following is the LogCat description**

```
04-07 01:48:53.439 7820-7820/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.adi.blogger, PID: 7820
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:172)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6290)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5478)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5363)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5359)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2141)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1525)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1488)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3506)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2969)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2127)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1243)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1479)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                    at java.lang.Class.getConstruct
04-07 01:48:53.469 7820-7820/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7820 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've put your `recyclerBlogView` inside another class, you need to mark it as `static`. So:

```
public static class recyclerBlogView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
```

Also see this Github issue: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/210